How enable/disable HDR Ubuntu Budgie?
I have installed the last version of Ubuntu Budgie.
Im trying to figure out if im working with or without HDR.
Fri Dec 13 21:22:09 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 560.35.03              Driver Version: 560.35.03      CUDA Version: 12.6     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Ti     Off |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   46C    P0             17W /  160W |     372MiB /   8188MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1554      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            166MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2175      G   /usr/bin/budgie-wm                             65MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3375      G   ...f9166a754324b12225ad6325a9ce4d8e063        112MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11112      G   /usr/bin/python3                                2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


*-display                 
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: AD106 [GeForce RTX 4060 Ti]
       fabricante: NVIDIA Corporation
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       nombre lógico: /dev/fb0
       versión: a1
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuración: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       recursos: iomemory:fa0-f9f iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:100 memoria:f5000000-f5ffffff memoria:fa00000000-fbffffffff memoria:fc00000000-fc01ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memoria:f6000000-f607ffff
  *-display
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: Raphael
       fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:0f:00.0
       versión: c6
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuración: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       recursos: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:79 memoria:fc10000000-fc1fffffff memoria:fc20000000-fc201fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memoria:f6500000-f657ffff


 lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm           5029888  0
nvidia_drm            122880  10
nvidia_modeset       1552384  12 nvidia_drm
nvidia               9736192  151 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
ecc                    45056  2 ecdh_generic,nvidia
video                  73728  2 amdgpu,nvidia_modeset

